# the company has signed or the company signed?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, past-simple

Why is it "this year the company has signed contracts to equip two large factories" and not "this year the company signed contracts to equip large factories"

So you say has signed contracts because the contracts signed still affect the present?

I thought though, that "this year the company signed" is right because the signing is already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has more to do with context than strict tense usage. Consider contracts that were signed *last* year and compare these two versions

> Last year the company has signed contracts to equip two large factories.
>
> Last year the company signed contracts to equip two large factories.

where clearly the second is correct. With more recent case of *this* year, both are grammatically correct, but in the context of the recent past it is more fluent to say

> This year the company has signed contracts to equip two large factories.

especially because "this year" is continuing, and there may be more contracts signed.

Comment: so basically its not wrong in terms of not correct to not use the has?

Comment: thank you, i was just kind of confused because I saw no wrong doing

Comment: For this year it is not wrong, but for last year it would be, because last year is in the past.